# nginx subdomains to subfolders

Tags: nginx, dns

I am trying to host few independent websites on one domain(few subdomains) with one server. Problem is that when I enter any of subdomains it displays me index.html from root folder. Domains record like below:

```
domain.xxx   (record A pointing to my vps server)
a.domain.xxx (record A pointing to my vps server)
b.domain.xxx (record A pointing to my vps server)
```

So each sub/domain points to exactly same address but I've installed nginx on my vps. I created directories like:

```
/usr/share/nginx - page root for phpmyadmin(common db)
/usr/share/nginx/a - first page
/usr/share/nginx/b - second page
... c/d/e/f/g - maybe in future
```

Important that every folder haves own index.html(with contet "a folder", "b folder", "root folder") and I setup in default config(sites-available/enabled):

```
#a
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name www.a.domain.xxx a.domain.xxx;
  root /usr/share/nginx/a;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  error_page 404 /404.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name){
                    return 404;
            }

            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
 }

#b
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name www.b.domain.xxx b.domain.xxx;
  root /usr/share/nginx/b;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  error_page 404 /404.html;

  location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name){
                    return 404;
            }

            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }
}

#phpmyadmin
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;


    location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

No matter I will try I always gets index.html from root folder. Funny thing is when I type sub/domain/folder it displays proper index.html

```
a.domain.xxx/a displays "a folder"
b.domain.xxx/a displays "a folder" 
domain.xxx/a   displays "a folder"
```

Maybe is there some configuration that I can try ip instead of those subdomain because there might be some DNS issues A records have been setted only few hours ago.

Second question is that those websites are built with angular 2 so additionaly you can point me some advice for future(atm I am using only index.html with static text)

Comment: Did you reload nginx? Did you reload the web page in your browser? What do you see in `nginx`'s log?

Comment: I found the problem setion #phpmyadmin was incorrect. 
After changing server_name for phpmyadmin to new subomain it works fine. Is there posibilty to test such configuraion without domains ? using only localhost ?